# Silverlight RIA DomainService with 2 million rows in a table

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, ria, domainservices

I'm doing a project that reads from an oracle database. I have used Silverlight RIA, and autogenerated DomainService since I'm not too concerned about structuring as I only worry about displaying the data.

My question is, that when I use the domaindatasource from the XAML, and use fiddler for debugging the WCF service and its calls, the first set of data from the table of useraccounts contains 2 million rows, and the DomainService times out.

Now I have tried increasing the timeout of the service to 20 mins, but still no avail, I get the error:

Load operation failed for query "GETUA_USERACCOUNTS". The http request to has exceeded the alloted timeout

Also out of the total 9 tables that I use, 3 tables have around 2 million rows, what would be the best method to approach this problem?

Comment: A client app should never need all 2 million records. Have you added paging/filtering to your display of the data?

Comment: Hi, thanks for that, I forgot to mention that I don't have to display all the data, I need to find the current record on the client end. A user enters a userID, and then I pull in all the information about that userId from various tables, and 3 tables have 2 million rows,so this is causing the timeouts.

Comment: That's a lot of data to send over to the Silverlight client app if you're just going to immediately filter it. This sounds like something you'd want to do server side, even if it requires multiple requests between Silverlight and your service endpoint.

Comment: Thanks avanek, I will try as you said, any best practices or examples that I can follow to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with RIA (I worked on a project that was only Silverlight + WCF), but for the most part I've found that using the [Repository software pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) helps with this kind of problem. Create a Getter method in the WCF layer that takes in the UserID and will return a single record instead of the entire data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To continue where TomTom left off, and Red asked, do your data filtering / processing on the server, before returning the results (Psuedocode)

```
public IQueriable<UserDTO> GetUserAccountDetails(string UserID)
{
    DataSet oneBazillionRows = SQLServer.GetAllUserRows();

    // LINQ to the rescue
    return from user in oneBillionRows
           where user.ID = UserID;
}
```

and your comsumer:

```
public void GetUserInfo()
{
    ServiceContext context = new ServiceContext();
    context.Load<UserDTO>(ServiceContext.GetUserAccountDetailsQuery(), load =>
    {
        // do some work here
        //like signalling the call is complete
        // or storing the data in your View Model
    }, null);
}
```

You consumer will then only recieve the one data row. The basic form is like so:

```
public IQueriable<ReturnType> WebService(Parameter parameter, ...)
{
    // Do all your work here, return minimal results
}
```

Consider: Invariably, the sever is going to be a lot beefier than your client machine. Let it do all the work of filtering / sorting / preprocessing results, and have it hand over minimal data. You will find your RIA implementations become much more snappy.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will try as you suggessted. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Use the ToTraceString method...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectquery.totracestring.aspx

...or an Oracle profiling tool to determine the SQL statement that is being used and confirm that it takes a long time to execute.

Use query optimization techniques such as adding indexes to speed it up.

Alternatively, write a stored procedure that returns the required result in a more efficient manner.

Comment: Thanks for the help Scott, I will try as you have suggested and will get back to you on how things go.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a DataPager, see here: http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Creating-applications-with-.NET-RIA-Services-Part-4-Adding-a-DomainDataSource.aspx

```
<navigation:Page x:Class="WebAdministrationTool.ManageUsers" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ria="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Ria.Controls"
    xmlns:local="..."
    xmlns:validation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data.DataForm">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

        <data:DataGrid x:Name="UsersGrid" 
                       IsReadOnly="True" 
                       AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                       ItemsSource="{Binding Data, ElementName=MyDataSource}" />

        <validation:DataPager x:Name="UsersPager"
                              PageSize="10" 
                              Source="{Binding Data, ElementName=MyDataSource}" />

        <ria:DomainDataSource x:Name="MyDataSource" LoadMethodName="LoadHugeAmountOfRows">
            <ria:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
                <local:MyDomainContext />
            </ria:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
        </ria:DomainDataSource>

    </Grid>

</navigation:Page>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm not actually displaying all the data, I have to find the current record from the actual list of all the 2 million records in the table. How would I proceed with this?

Comment: You should add a FilterDescriptor to the DomainDataSource. See sample implementation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.domaindatasource.filterdescriptors%28VS.91%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks again DenisPostu, but I think I should have been more clear with the question. here is the situtation that I'm having.. I forgot to mention that I don't have to display all the data, I need to find the current record on the client end. A user enters a userID, and then I pull in all the information about that userId from various tables, and 3 tables have 2 million rows,so this is causing the timeouts

Comment: If you dont ahve to displa data, DONT PULL IT. That simple. This is not a RIA problem, this is 20 years of design practice out of the door. Put in a filter. Get only the data you indend to show. SImple like that.

Comment: Thanks TomTom, so when a user enters a userID, for me to get details of the user from the table, I do have to iterate through the rows to find out all the information on the client end or on the server end? so how can I do as suggested, please guide me on this, as I'm a student, and willing to learn things

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and to handle this i created stored procedures on my database to do the work and only spit back the information i needed.  There is not a lot of info on adding stored procedures to RIA but here is a shot on what i know works.

1. create your stored procedure
2. update your Database Model in your project to include the stored procedure
3. in Model Browser right click and add function import.  here you get to name and decide how the data is returned (make it easy on yourself and try to return an object already in your DomainService.metadata.cs file)
4. if creating new return object add it to your DomainService.metadata.cs file
5. in your domain service add a public method that returns the result list.

   ```
   public IQueryable<FWCUser> UpdateFWCUserWithUserProfileID(int userProfileID, int fwcUserID)
   {
      return this.ObjectContext.UpdateFWCUserWithUserProfileID(userProfileID, fwcUserID).AsQueryable();
   }
   ```
6. build your project and call the method as needed from code behind

   ```
   FWCDomainContext context = new FWCDomainContext();
   context.Load(context.UpdateFWCUserWithUserProfileIDQuery(num1, num2), Completed, null);
   ```

Comment: Thannks for the help, really appreciated. Cheers